# Crystal Reports deployment-Shared Server

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, crystal-reports

Hi
I am trying to publish my site on a shared server. They don't have crystal reports run time install on the server and they are not willing to do so. Is there any workaround so that i can deploy my site with crystal report support on shared server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do it on THAT server, but you could run you main app on THAT server and call/link/run your reports from a different server.

I realize that may not be possible, but if you're asking can you run Crystal Reports on a server without the Crystal runtime on THAT server, the answer is no.